# Is there a name for the event where someone leaving a room finds themselves back in the exact same room?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the (event / affect / situation) (where / when) a character uses a door that leads back into the same room that they are leaving?

This is better described in the post.
https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/26820/when-was-the-horror-film-technique-where-a-character-opens-a-door-to-the-same-ro

There are two links to names of this on TV tropes (Alien Geometries and Going in circle).
I find that Alien Geometries is much to broad and could be used to describe many different situations (ie. Mario 64 - Infinite stairs) and I think that Going in circle implies that there is a journey before returning to the same spot.

An example of this event can be seen in the Star Trek: TNG episode "Where Silence Has Lease" when Work and Riker are on the bridge of the second Enterprise.

Sample sentence: "I don't realy have any options, I'm stuck in a [...]. Staying here or using the door doesn't matter at all. In both cases I've changed nothing." - Door and location are metaphors for a persons choice not impacting the enviorment they are in.

Using the example from Star Trek TNG:
Worf and Riker were stuck in a [...]. Even if worf went through the door he would still be on the same bridge as Riker who had never moved.

Comment: I see it used often in movies but its not limited to movies. There are games that use this as a mechanic. (ie: Portal)

Comment: mechanism, not mechanic. That's a person who fixes cars.

Comment: This frustrating deja vu was the subject of the film Ground Hog Day.

Comment: There are words for nonexistent things in English, like _unicorn_. But there is isn't a word in English for every possible nonexistent thing. That would be very large lexicon, probably uncountably large. Hard to look things up.

Comment: @Lambie *The way something works works or is done* is more often referred as *the mechanics* plural, but it is often used in the singular to refer to one element of the way a game or system works. ["To understand what a game mechanic is, first it’s important to be familiar with another term important to video games: gameplay."](https://www.gamedesigning.org/learn/basic-game-mechanics/)

Comment: @GArthurBrown I have never seen it used in the singular like that.  I doubt it's elsewhere other than in games.

Comment: @Lambie ["The  operating  sys-tem  also  is  the  maintenance  mechanic  of  the  system."](https://hugepdf.com/queue/download-a-role-of-virtual-machine-in-operating-system_pdf?queue_id=-1) ["I started with the most basic and necessary mechanic of the system, the actual act of adding a course to your schedule."](https://medium.com/@alecmartin/sketch-prototype-test-wireframe-553edd7aad2f) ["... the  mechanic  of the  system  which students can easily  verify"](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/1335/1/012011/pdf)

Comment: @GArthurBrown Obviously, "The operating system is the maintenance mechanic of the system" is a metaphor for what regulates the system, "keeps it going" or running smoothly just like a car mechanic. So these uses are just like a car mechanic to a car.

Comment: @Lambie And the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***paradox***

It is a type of reflexivity: I have always heard it called an

***Escher paradox***

[image]

> ***"I don't realy have any options, I'm stuck in an [Esher paradox]. Staying here or using the door doesn't matter at all. In both cases I've changed nothing."***

I think Euler comes into play here somewhere.

---

Based on comments from the OP, a more updated alternative could be :

***"endless loop"***

> ***"I don't really have any options, I'm stuck in an [endless loop]. Staying here or using the door doesn't matter at all. In both cases I've changed nothing."***

Comment: Would you say that the person experienced an Escher paradox or that they used a room and or door that was an Escher paradox

Comment: "I don't realy have any options, I'm stuck in [...]. Staying here or using the door doesn't matter at all. In both cases I've changed nothing." - Door and location are metaphors for a persons choice not impacting the enviorment they are in.

Comment: Revolving door.

Comment: This is bringing up dim memories of non-orientable surfaces. It seems like there are two doors exiting the room, but they're the same door...

Comment: Ah! Nightmare memories of the "Pirates of Penzance"